recoup diskspace from MS windows partitions
I have an old Dell XPS 9570 laptop with 500GB diskspace. Sometime back I repurposed the laptop to Ubuntu.
Currently Ubuntu uses only 100GB of diskspace. I would like to recoup the other 400GB being used by the Windows partitions and mount my home directory on the recouped space. Here is the listing of current partitions from fdisk:
sudo fdisk -l

Device              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1333247   1331200   650M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1333248    1595391    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    1595392  764108799 762513408 363.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4  968908800  970936319   2027520   990M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5  970936320  997861375  26925056  12.8G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6  997863424 1000214527   2351104   1.1G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p7  764108800  764110847      2048     1M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8  764110848  765161471   1050624   513M Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p9  765161472  766212095   1050624   513M Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p10 766212096  968908799 202696704  96.7G Linux filesystem
and here is the image of the disk partitions


Ideally here is what I would like to do:

Delete the windows partitions /dev/nvme0n1p2 to /dev/nvme0n1p6
Create a new partition from the space recouped in step#1
Copy the linux data from partition /dev/nvme0n1p10 to the newly created partition
Make the newly created partition as the primary linux partition mounted on /

Is it possible to do this? How can I do this without losing any data?

Whenever making major changes you must have good backups. If any data in Windows you need that also. And backup of /home, list of installed apps, any server type apps in / (root) and /etc files you may have edited (I edit grub). To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions
Move Home &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455822&p=14010437#post14010437

Tip: In order to avoid problems, delete the partitions, and in the unallocated space create an ext4 partition, then mount it on your ~/
